# Custom error message is not showing on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages

// VFP

```html
<apex:page controller="NumberClassErrorMessage" wizard="true">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Number Calculations">
            <apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
            
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Calculator" >
                <font color="#E70E38">
                Enter Number 1: <apex:inputText value="{!Num1}" />
                Enter Number 2: <apex:inputText value="{!Num2}"/>
                    </font>
                <apex:commandButton value="Calculate" action="{!calculator}" reRender="xyz" />
                <apex:outputLabel id="xyz" value="{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(message), '\\n', '<br/>')}" escape="false" />       
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

```java
// Controller
public class NumberClassErrorMessage {
    
    public integer Num1 {set; get;}
    public integer Num2 {set; get;}
    public string message {set; get;}
    public void calculator()
    {
        integer add,sub,mul,div ;
        
        //if(acc.AccountNumber == '' || acc.AccountNumber == null)
        //ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please enter Account number'));
        /*if(NumberA < 0){
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.Error, 'First number is negative!'));
}
*/      
        if(Num1 == null || Num1 < 0){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Kindly Enter Valid Amount in Number 1'));
            
        }
        if(Num2 == null || Num2 < 0){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Kindly Enter Valid Amount in Number 2'));
        }
        
        add = Num1+Num2;
        sub = Num1-Num2;
        mul = Num1*Num2;
        // div = Num1/Num2;
        
        message = 'Addition of Numbers :' +add + '\n' + 
            'Substraction of Numbers :' +sub +  '\n' +
            'Multiplication of Numbers :' +mul +  '\n' +
            'Division of Numbers :'  ; // +div
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the apex:pageMessages id in the rerender attribute, so it's not getting updated when the button is clicked. Set both items to rerender.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Calculate" action="{!calculator}" reRender="xyz,showmsg" />
```

In addition, it appears that the default value when the field is blank is being set to zero, so you need to convert from a string:

```
public String Num1 {set; get;}
public String Num2 {set; get;}
public string message {set; get;}
public void calculator()
{
    
    if(String.isBlank(this.num1) || !this.num1.isNumeric()) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Kindly Enter Valid Amount in Number 1'));
    }
    if(String.isBlank(this.num2) || !this.num2.isNumeric()) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Kindly Enter Valid Amount in Number 2'));
    }
    if(ApexPages.hasMessages()) {
        message = null;
        return;
    }
    Integer Num1 = Integer.valueOf(num1), num2 = Integer.valueOf(num2);
    integer add,sub,mul,div ;
    
    add = Num1+Num2;
    sub = Num1-Num2;
    mul = Num1*Num2;
    // div = Num1/Num2;
    
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Here is your output!'));
    message = 'Addition of Numbers :' +add + '\n' + 
        'Substraction of Numbers :' +sub +  '\n' +
        'Multiplication of Numbers :' +mul +  '\n' +
        'Division of Numbers :'  ; // +div
}
```